# "addAutoComplete is not defined", great but with jQuery js defines it?

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This (probably easily solved) problem has been appearing and disappearing for a while.

We are developing a Django Web App which is using the AutoCompleteWidget.

We keep getting the following error in Firebug

"addAutoComplete is not defined"

Of course the AutoComplete does not work as we want it to in the form.

I realize there are namespace and inclusion of proper javascript file considerations.

My main question right now is:

Which jquery *.js file should I include to get the definition of 'addAutoComplete'?

Thanks.

PS the generated HTML code in question is:

```
<input type="text" name="department" id="id_department" value="" maxlength="Department" />
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    addAutoComplete("id_department", function(html_id) {
        $("#"+html_id).autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: '/ajax_select/ajax_lookup/ucddept',
            initial: '',
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#"+html_id).val(ui.item.value);
                $("#"+html_id).trigger("added");
                return false;
            }
        }).autocompletehtml();
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2):

No properly written jQuery plugin will define a global function `addAutoComplete`.

Try this. It will work if you include jQuery UI:

```
$("#id_department").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: '/ajax_select/ajax_lookup/ucddept',
    initial: '',
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $('#id_department');
        $this.val(ui.item.value);
        $this.trigger("added");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, and please accept my apologies for my delay in responding.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that by "the AutoCompleteWidget", you mean the Django Ajax Select app provided here: https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects.

The addAutoComplete function you're missing is defined in the static/js/ajax-select.js file inside the app. If it's not being included in your rendered page, it's probably because you didn't set the **AJAX_SELECT_INLINES** variable in your settings.py file correctly. This setting tells the app how it should include the file.

Check out the **settings.py** entry in the source's README for more info. https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects/blob/master/README.md.

Really, read that whole document thoroughly if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: Thanks I will,  this project has been much like trying to get a drink of water from someone else's firehose. so please accept my apologies for my demonstrated ignorance ont hsi topic.  I'll re-read that whole document now.